# Connecting to mssqlnative

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a working website running on Unix that connects via VPN to a SQL Server database using dblib.

The connection has been created in years past like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=192.168.2.4:1433;dbname=Andover;charset=utf8', 'UserName', 'Password');
$Query= "Select * From tablename";
$Stmt = $pdo->prepare($Query);
```

The new connection method I've been told to use is as follows:

```
<?php 
$serverName = "192.168.2.4,1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433) 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Andover", "UID"=>"UserName", "PWD"=>"Password"); 
$pdo = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if( $pdo ) { 
     echo "Connection established.<br />"; 
}else{ 
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />"; 
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
} 
echo "****************EOF************";
?>
```

And this seems to work, running through without error.

However, when I try to use a table it fails:

```
$sql= "SELECT * from TableName";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

The error is:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource

What do I need to do to be able to access the table?

Comment: You simply need to use `sqlsrv_query()`. All `sqlsrv` functions are not object oriented.

Comment: Who told you to use this connection method and WHY?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `SQLSRV` part of the PHP Driver for SQL Server, which is different from the `PDO_SQLSRV` version and is not object oriented. The return value from the `sqlsrv_connect()` function is not an object, it's a PHP connection resource or `false` if a connection cannot be successfully created and opened.

In your specific situation you simply need a combination of `sqlsrv_query()` and `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`. As is explained in the documentation  *... The sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries...* .

```
<?php 
$serverName = "192.168.2.4,1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433) 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Andover", "UID"=>"UserName", "PWD"=>"Password"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if ($conn === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}    
$sql  = "SELECT * from TableName";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo print_r($row, true);
}
```

Of course, a PDO approach is also an option:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.2.4,1433";
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=Andover", "UserName", "Password");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql  = "SELECT * from TableName";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo print_r($row, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlsrv it's not PDO and have different sintax, first argument it's resource of connection to MSSQL, that's why you recieve your error.

Full working code must be like this:

```php
$serverName = "192.168.2.4,1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433) 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Andover", "UID"=>"UserName", "PWD"=>"Password"); 
$mssconnect = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if($mssconnect === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$sql= "SELECT * from TableName";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $mssconnect, $sql);
if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt)
if($result === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> When you use `sqlsrv_connect()`, it doesn't return a PDO instance but a resource on success, or false on failure.

---

Using the `SQLSRV` API's functions.

```
$serverName = "192.168.2.4,1433";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "Andover", "UID" => "UserName", "PWD" => "Password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true),  E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true),  E_USER_ERROR);
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // You can now access your data in $row array.
    print_r($row);
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

Comment: How your answer is different from two existing answers?